# A comma before "you" to emphasize a noun?

Tags: commas

> I know you, trainers, have been itching to collect rare pokemons in the wild world.

Is the comma usage acceptable based from the sentence? Or should I just omit both the noun and commas?

Comment: One could make a case for "trainers" being a supplementary appositive NP, marked by the commas. But I think the commas should be dropped and "you trainers" treated as an NP consisting of the personal determinative "you" functioning as determiner of "trainers". "You trainers have been itching ..." is then a declarative content clause (with "you trainers" as subject) functioning as complement of "know".

Answer (score 2, accepted):

I know of no guide to punctuation that would find that acceptable.

Of course punctuation is not grammar: it does not even exist in English speech.

How might such emphasis be handled?

In speech, “you trainers” might be shouted. In writing, it might be shown in bold letters: **you trainers**.

Moreover, there are numerous semantic ways to emphasize that it is trainers who are eager.

> You trainers have been specially eager...

> You trainers in particular have been itching ...

> No one itches more than you trainers ...

> Naturally, you trainers are the most eager ...

English has plenty of words and plenty of syntactical forms to make your intended meaning clear.